# Connected always returning as valid in SQLite (using C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, validation

I'm trying to connected to a local .sqlite file via a c# WPF application, and I've built the following two methods:

```
    private SQLiteConnection dbConn;

    public string dbPath()
    {
        dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\ommited\file\path\ChinookSqlite.sqlite;");
        return isConnected();
    }
```

and the `isConnected()` method:

```
    public string isConnected()
    {
        try
        {
            dbConn.Open();
            return "VALIDATED";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return "FAILED";
        }
    }
```

These two are then ran through the `MainWindow` of the WPF front-end, via this:

```
    dbConnection myDB = new dbConnection();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dbConnCheck.Content = myDB.dbPath();
    }
```

My problem is that if I change the explicit file path string (the location, not the file name) the connection will **not** validate. 
If I change the file name (from `ChinookSqlite.Sqlite` to `dddddddChinookSqlite.sqlite`) it **will** validate, even if the file name is wrong.

Can anyone offer some advice as to why this is happening? When an explicit string wasn't used it would always validate regardless, the closest I've come to accurately checking the connection has been with an explicit file path string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the status of your connection your shouldn't rely in a `try/catch` structure. You've got `State`property for that. So your `isConnected`method should be something like:

```
public bool isConnected()
{
     if (dbConn != null && dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
     {
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         return false;
     }
}
```

And then change `dbPath` method. In SQLite you can add `FailIfMissing=True` parameter,which will throw an exception if the database file is missing.Otherways,if the file is not found,a new one is created:

```
public string dbPath()
{
    try
    {
         dbConn = 
             new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\ommited\file\path\ChinookSqlite.sqlite;
                 FailIfMissing=True");

         if (!isConnected())
         {
              dbConn.Open();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         //the database file does not exists..
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what `(!isConnected)` is meant to do? You've helped immensely but I'm a little lost on that part. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `isConnected` just returns true if the conection to the database is already opened, or false if it isn't.So `!isConnected` check if the conection is not opened. Anyway, i think your problem was not understanding that in SQLite, if you try to open a database and the filename does not exists, it would create a new one unless you use `FailIfMissing=True` parameter

Comment: You're right, I didn't understand that part. Shortly after I read your answer I went into the bin folder and found about 15 0kb database files! My problem at the moment the `!isConnected` call is erroring due to using the `!` on a method.

Comment: Notice that my `isConected`method returns bool. Check that

Comment: Hmm sorry @JayGould, i had a typo, it should be `!isConnected()` i missed the parenthesis

Comment: isConnected is a `bool` for me too, error is still the same.